# What's the best way to handle initialization errors in Play! Framework 2.0?

Tags: scala, error-handling, initialization, playframework-2.0

Imagine I have an application written using [Play 2](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Home).  Imagine that application needs to grab hold of some things on startup (read a config file, grab some resources from JNDI, that kind of thing).  Play handily gives us the [GlobalSettings](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal) object that we can use to hook into start and stop events:

```
import play.api._

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  var someResource: Resource = _

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    // might throw an exception if the path doesn't exist
    resource = JNDI.grabThing("/some/path").asInstanceOf[Resource]
  }  

}
```

The problem is - what can we do if the initialisation fails?  It seems that this is only executed when Play receives the first request for the application.  If we throw an exception, that causes that request to fail, but the application keeps on running.

Ideally, what I'd like is to stop the application from starting at all if this block doesn't complete successfully.  Unfortunately, calling `Play.stop()` doesn't actually seem to, well, stop Play.  I can see that the [`Server`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/server/Server.scala) trait defines `def stop()`, which looks promising but I can't figure out a way to get hold of the `Server` instance from inside my application.

Perhaps I'm looking at this the wrong way, and I'm not *supposed* to be able to stop Play (or even just my app) from inside my application, so suggestions for other approaches are welcome.

What's the best way to handle these errors?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I'm lying.  Play only continues to serve requests after an exception in `onStart` if you're running in dev mode (`play run`).  If started with `play start` (i.e. production mode) an exception here will terminate the server, which is exactly what I wanted.

It does appear to leave the `RUNNING_PID` file lying around, which is irritating, but that's a separate issue...